# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException for some https url in nutch 1.13

Tags: java, nutch

I try crawling seed urls that are http/https 
but for few https urls i get below error
FetcherThread INFO  api.HttpRobotRulesParser (168) - Couldn't get robots.txt for https://corporate.douglas.de/investors/?lang=en: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

on other hand https://www.integrafin.co.uk/annual-reports/ is crawled perfectly fine

below is my configuration
plugin.includes
  protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|text)|index-(basic|anchor|more|static|links)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|urlmeta|language-identifier

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the certificate of server https://corporate.douglas.de/investors/?lang=en in the "cacerts" file of the JVM that runs your code.

First, download the certificate using Chrome:
[image]

Then, click in "details" tab and then in button "Copy to file"
[image]

In the wizard, select the option "DER binary.... (.CER)"

Now, you can use the tool "portecle" (http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to add the certificate to the cacert file in your JVM followin this steps http://portecle.sourceforge.net/import-trusted-cert.html

Hope works for you.

Comment: so this has to be done manually for any URL that have same issue , is there any way by which this can be done automatically via nutch?

Comment: Excuse me, I dont have idea about how nutch works.
Anyway this solutions works for urls in the same domain or domains that using the same certificate.
Maybe you can add to your cacerts the certificate of the certification entity. This way you is telling your JVM "ey¡ trust in all domains signed by this certification entity".

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a more recent version of Nutch, or compile directly from master, and then give a try to the `http.tls.certificates.check` setting, from (https://github.com/apache/nutch/pull/388). This will essentially allow you to skip the TLS/SSL verification.

Comment: the JIRA is not pushed into latest Nutch 1.X version . So i tried to make the changes manually and compile.The changes in lib-http and protocol-httpclient compiled but the build failed(cannot find DummyX509TrustManager) while trying to build protocol-http along with the changes in the JIRA i also added <import plugin="protocol-httpclient"/> to plugin\protocol-http\plugin.xml

Comment: The PR is merged, so if you checkout master and build Nutch you should be able to use it.

Comment: i was successful in building the plugins(copied the plugins to my application plugins folder and i am using nutch 1.13) but when i start using the new plugins(lib-http/protocol-httpclient/protocol-http) now i get a new error        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.nutch.protocol.Content.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/nutch/metadata/Metadata;Lorg/apache/nutch/util/MimeUtil;)V
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase.getProtocolOutput(HttpBase.java:339)

Comment: Have you run all the tests after the build?

Comment: i was using the new plugins with nutch 1.13 , hence was getting the error for all seedurls .Now i am using the new plugins with nutch 1.15 and i stille get error but only for seed urls that need certificates and now the error has changed from Couldn't get robots.txt for https://www.novami.com/investors/lobby/: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure to  Couldn't get robots.txt for https://www.novami.com/investors/lobby/: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: i am also getting same error with nutch 1.16, please let me know if any one have resolved this issue.